# Sort .csv file alphabetically doesn't work correctly when there is a hyphen

Tags: linux, sort, cygwin

I want to sort a .csv file which contains different names. But there is a problem when a name has a hyphen at the beginning.

I tried things like:

```
sort -k1 -t
sort -k1 -g -t
sort -k1 -n -t
```

input:

```
other data 
Acid 
other data
Acid
-acid
Acid
-acid
Acid
etc.
```

output:

```
random data
Acid
-acid
-acid
Acid
-acid
etc.
```

want:

```
-acid
-acid
-acid
Acid
Acid 
etc.
```

Comment: With sort file.csv, I got expected output ???

Comment: What is your locale (in particular, `LC_COLLATE`)? Try `LC_COLLATE=C sort < input`

Comment: Read this: https://serverfault.com/questions/95579/unix-sort-treats-dash-characters-as-invisible/95593

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Background

It's unclear what version of `sort` you're using but on a CentOS 7.x system using this version of sort:

```
$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.22
```

And this sample input file:

```
$ cat file
other data
Acid
other data
Acid
-acid
Acid
-acid
Acid
```

This looks to match what you're looking for in your output:

```
$ sort -k1 file
-acid
-acid
Acid
Acid
Acid
Acid
other data
other data
```

#### Language & locale

In the above, my locale is set as follows:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

You can get a complete list with this command:

```
$ locale -a
aa_DJ
aa_DJ.iso88591
aa_DJ.utf8
aa_ER
aa_ER@saaho
...
```

If you're running into some issue with your locale you can tell `sort` to use the `C` locale to work around these issues:

```
$ LC_ALL=C sort -k1 file
-acid
-acid
Acid
Acid
Acid
Acid
other data
other data
```

If you have a locale such as `de_DE`, the sorting would be different:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=de_DE sort -k1 file
Acid
Acid
Acid
Acid
-acid
-acid
other data
other data
```

Again to control this, you can put set the locale to `C`.

#### References

- [Locale (computer software) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software))
- [Locale - ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale)